# How to transfer database to text file - and from text file to database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to transfer database to text file -  and from text file to database in SQL Server 2008

I try something like: `select * into 'd:\test.txt'  from men`

but it doesn't work.

- i need it in query solution not in the sql-server backup or similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

A. better use backup to do it.

B. There are tools that generate a "create" script for an entire database (like TOAD in commercial version).

What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

If you want to code this - you can select the table into a data reader, and then for each row append it to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b): "Tasks -> Back Up"  or "Tasks -> Generate Scripts" or "Tasks -> Export -> Flat file destination".

Alternatively you could use the [bcp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) command line tool.

Comment: i need it in query solution not in the sql-server backup or similar tool.